# problem with a validation table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a validation table `Person Type` with fields `type_id` and `type`. In the `type` filed I need to store the following values: `PubCrsAtt, Health Professional, Trainee, Qualified Trainer, Customer`.

My questions:

How can I add `Graduation Date` to `Qualified Trainer` and `Job Title` to `Health Professional` within the validation table?

How can I distinguish `Health Professional` as a subcategory of `Trainee` within the validation table?

Any help will be much appreciated
Zan

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you want to be shooting yourself long before the end of the project. Instead, you should (I'd say ***must!***) add two more columns: Graduation_Date and Job_Title. So your table would look something like this:

```
field 1   field 2   field 3      field 4
typeid     type    grad_date    job_title
```

You might also want to add a field for the person's name. (And maybe the person's office telephone, office location, and anything else interesting that describes one single person.)

To add Health_Professional as a subcategory of Trainee (or of any other type), you should add yet another field, call it subtype:

```
field 1   field 2  field 3   field 4      field 5
typeid     type    subtype  grad_date    job_title
```

To understand why it has to be this way, google 'database normalization'.